# pthread_join blocks my code

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

can you explain me why the following use of pthread_join doesn't work?it blocks my code.
if I comment those 3 lines, my code does what is expected, but obviously I don't know if threads are terminated(in my code there is no problem for that, but in a bigger situation there is).

```
int k=0;
pthread_mutex_t mutex= PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

struct primi{
   int s;
   int temp;
};
struct example{
   int c;
   struct primi primissimi;
};
void *funzione_thread(void* args);

void prepare(void){
   printf("preparing locks...\n");
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);   }
void parent(void){
   printf("parent unlocking locks...\n");
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);}
void child(void){
   printf("child unlocking locks...\n");
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);  }
void *thr_fn(void *arg){
   printf("thread started...\n");
   return(0);}


void *funzione_thread(void* args){
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   struct example *exthread = args;
   struct example locale = *exthread;
   locale.primissimi.s++;pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   printf("local is %d original is %d\n",locale.primissimi.s,exthread->primissimi.s);
   exthread->primissimi.s = locale.primissimi.s;
   printf("after it is%d\n",exthread->primissimi.s);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}


int ffork(struct example *extmp){
  pthread_t id[5];
  int i;
  while(k<3){
    k++;
    pthread_create(&id[k],NULL,funzione_thread,extmp);
    }
  printf("now k is %d\n\n",k);
  for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
    pthread_join( id[i] ,NULL );
    printf("waited thread %d\n",i);
    }
  printf("threads completed\n");
  pthread_exit (NULL);  
  //return 1;
}
 int main(int argc, char** argv){

  struct example *ex = malloc(sizeof(*ex));
  int pid,tmp;
      pthread_t tid;

      if ((err = pthread_atfork(prepare, parent, child)) != 0){
           printf("can't install fork handlers");
           exit(-1);}
      pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thr_fn, 0);
      sleep(1);
      pid=fork();
      if(pid==0){
         ex->c=1;
         ex->primissimi.s=1;
         if((tmp=ffork(ex))!=1){
        printf("errore in ffork\n");
        sleep(2);
        exit(0);
        }
    else{printf("tutto ok in ffork\n");
        sleep(2);
        exit(0);
        }
    }//fine figlio

else{
    sleep(10);
}
return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has no protection against calling `fork` with the mutex locked. Since the thread that locked the mutex doesn't exist in the child, it cannot unlock the mutex ... ever. Any thread in the child that tries to acquire the mutex will deadlock, waiting for the non-existent thread to release the lock.

There are a lot of possible fixes, but the simplest is probably to hold the mutex across the call to `fork`. You can use an [atfork](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/pthread_atfork.html) handler to do this. Arrange the handler to acquire the mutex before the `fork` and release it after (in both the parent and child).

You really need to know what you're doing to use `fork` together with pthreads, unless you're going to immediately `exec` in the child.

Comment: You definitely cannot hold a mutex across the fork and unlock it in the child, because only the thread which locked the mutex is allowed to unlock it. Anything else results in undefined behavior (or an error if it's an error-checking mutex).

Comment: Also note that, per POSIX: "If a multi-threaded process calls fork(), the new process shall contain a replica of the calling thread and its entire address space, possibly including the states of mutexes and other resources. Consequently, to avoid errors, the child process may only execute async-signal-safe operations until such time as one of the exec functions is called."

Comment: by the way, I'm trying to use atfork() with prepare that locks mutex,parent that unlock it and child too, but the result is the same.
Using pthread_join it doesn't work.

Comment: @R.. Are you saying me that I cannot do that?neither with pthread_atfork()? I modified code, using it, but no great changes.

Comment: Your code tries to join `id[0]`, which doesn't correspond to any thread you actually created.

Comment: @rschirin: The intent of `pthread_atfork`'s design is that you be able to do what you're doing, but per the standard, it's not possible; `pthread_mutex_unlock` states explicitly that a thread different from the one that locked the mutex cannot unlock it, and that attempts to do so must result in an error if it's an error-checking mutex, and undefined behavior otherwise. It may seem to work on a non-error-checking mutex but that's very system-specific and unreliable. It will definitely fail on all real-world systems if you use an error-checking mutex.

Comment: @R..thanks!do you advise me to change approach in my situation?i.e. replace fork() in any way?

Comment: I would recommend calling `fork` before you create any threads. If you must call `fork` in a threaded program, immediately call `exec`.